# Meaning of the name of Linux's rcS script?

Tags: embedded-linux, init

The `/etc/init.d/rcS` script is (as most of you may know) parsed by the init system during the Linux boot process.
Does anybody know what the name of that file (**rcS**) stands for?

Searching online just gave me the *RCS - Revision Control System*...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The S in rcS goes back to the run level 1 in SysV init which was the "single user mode".

For the "rc" itself you have to back in history quite a while. See http://www.catb.org/~esr/writings/taoup/html/ch10s03.html for an explanation.

Comment: Yeah, got it .Thanks, so how about r and c ?

Comment: As the title of the linked page says: **Run-Control** Files... Therefore it may boil down to something like *run-control-SingleUserMode*

Answer (score -2):

You are looking for /etc/init.d/rcS.

Comment: Hi, I konw this . Just wanna know  what rcS is short for ? or there is no meaning at all ?